# Passing expression to "include" attribute in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I discovering some really fun stuff with Thymeleaf and spring MVC and how it all blends in. Now I do not believe that there is no solution to this problem:

So to include a fragment in an element according to documentation you are supposed to use this expression:

```
<div th:include="path/to/fragment/template :: fragmentName"><div/>
```

And it works, but this does not:

```
<div th:include="${model_nav_attribute}"><div/> //where model_nav_attribute = "path/to/fragment/template :: fragmentName"
```

This does not work, I did not get into debugging details yet but my notion tells me it is due to the fact that the operator `::` is not evaluated during `${model_nav_attribute}` evaluation as this code snippet works fine:

```
<div th:include="${model_nav_template_path} :: ${model_nav_fragment_name}"><div/> // model_nav_template_path = "where path/to/fragment/template and model_nav_template_path = "fragmentName"
```

But then again it is too tedious to pass around two arguments.

So if

```
    <div th:include="${model_nav_attribute}"><div/> //where model_nav_attribute = "path/to/fragment/template :: fragmentName"
```

is by no means possible and or correct what would your suggestions be of achieving similar effect? (which is to have one root view with interchangeable content based on URI path, arguments etc... at Single Page Application) I wish to keep fragments separated in different html files so that they wouldn't clutter up hence I will need to change paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

`<div th:include="__${model_nav_attribute}__"><div/>`

The **__** preprocessingthe expression before the normal one.

More information: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing